# Handling CORS policy in React Native (Expo) & Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, expo, cors

I'm making a hybrid-app (multiplatform-app) with React Native Expo and Spring Boot,
but an App in React Native (with Expo) CAN'T send  any HTTP request (fetch)  even if I set `addCorsMappings` in Spring Boot.

Normal HTML (JavaScript) can get the data from the server, but App in React Native CAN'T in BOTH iOS and Android.

[image]

[image]

What should I do now?

Setting in Spring boot:

```js
package com.example.apiTest.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

public class webConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry){
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","HEAD","PATCH","OPTIONS")
                .allowCredentials(true);
        

    }


}
```

GetTest.html (this code works when server is running):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HTTP GET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="sendRequest()">Send Request</button>

  <script>
    function sendRequest() {
      fetch('http://localhost:8090/member/test')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log('Success:', data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

react native app:

```
const testFunc = async () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:8090/member/test')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
};
```

```
const LogInPage = () => {
  const [id, onChangeid] = React.useState();
  const [passWord, onChangeText2] = React.useState();
  const[disabled, setDisabled]=React.useState(false);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>        
  
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={testFunc} 
        disabled={disabled}
        style={styles.button}
          
        
        >
          <Text style={{color : 'white'}}>로그인</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
    
  );
};
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,

    top : 10,
    
  },

  container:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent : 'center',
    paddingHorizontail : 10,
    
  },

  button:{
    alignItems : 'center',
    backgroundColor : 'gray',
    padding : 10,
    
  },

  text:{
    color : 'white',
    fontWeight : 'bold',
  },

});

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    LogInPage()

  );
};
```

I tried @CrossOrigin Annotation but, doesn't work,
but React native app can send request to online free API test.

Why react native doesn't work in this case?

I want React Native App to send request to the server....